# Remove left and right padding in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

How can I remove the padding within the canvas element when using chart.js? *(See red area in the image below)*

I already set the [Padding](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/layout.html#padding) Option to 0, but that doesn't seem to effect the spacing on the left and right inside the Canvas itself.

Ideally the labels of the X axis would start and end as well where the chart area ends. Not sure how to achieve it.

[image: Left and right spacing]

The blue area is the canvas area. The red is the spacing I would like to remove.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question

Answer (score 0):

use drawTicks in yAxes

```
options: {
    scales: { 
        yAxes: {
            grid: {
                drawTicks: false,
            },
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Hard to say without showing your code, but to me it could look like the labels adding padding to the sides.

Have you tried rotating the labels to see if it helps:

```
 options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          autoSkip: false,
          maxRotation: 90,
          minRotation: 90
        }
      }]
    }
  }
```